# How can I remove all of the plugins from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, plugins

I want to remove all plugins from Firefox, until now I have only had success with removing all addons. (I don't mind if I have to reinstall Firefox to achieve this)

How can I remove all of the plugins from Firefox?

Comment: have you tried synaptic? usually all plugins are there...

Comment: i try synaptics , but in this way i should remove plugin after plugin with manual search

Comment: apt-cache rdepends firefox gets you a list of all packages that depend on firefox.  some creative grepping will thin that list out fast.  this does assume the plugin was added through deb not manually.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what plugins you have installed. The default ones are in `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`, so you can try renaming them. On the other hand, you could also searching through the installed packages and uninstalling the plugins one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove your plugins in Firefox to make it faster. I suppose that is the reason you need plugins removed.

You can either disable all plugins by going to Firefox menu in Tools - Addons - Plugins, and choose manually for each plugin to 'Never Activate' or you can choose 'Ask to Activate' instead for one or more of your plugins if you think you want to use them in the future.

You can also try [this package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/galternatives/) called G-Alternatives which will allow you to change or completely remove certain plugins for Firefox like Flash player or Java. The package can be installed through the Software Center, but if you want to download and install right from the link I gave you don't forget to first choose your Ubuntu version (eg. 13.10 , 12.04 ....). You can easily harm your system if you don't know what you're doing so it is up to you to use G-Alternatives package or not.